# Mediaelement video failing in ipad

Tags: javascript, video, mediaelement.js

Hi im using mediaelement player wich is great actually, the problem is even if i convert the file to all the formats, in ipad is strange some times i just hear audio, some times nothing plays , and just once, just one time the video play with the play image logo all the time over it.. what is wrong with my mediaelement code

```
<div class="videoquon">
         <div class='my-video-close' onclick='player.pause();'></div>


        <div id="marfvideo"><video width="530" height="377" id="player" controls="controls">
         <source src="media/mp4/ingles.mp4" type="video/mp4" title="mp4">
         <source src="media/webm/ingles.webm" type="video/webm" title="webm">
         <source src="media/ogv/ingles.ogv" type="video/ogg" title="ogg">
         <source src="media/flv/ingles.flv" type="video/flv" title="flv">
         <p>Tu navegador necesita ser actualizado.</p>
         </video></div>

<script>
$('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({
  // if the <video width> is not specified, this is the default
  defaultVideoWidth: 530,
  // if the <video height> is not specified, this is the default
  defaultVideoHeight: 377,
  autosizeProgress: true,
  // Hide controls when playing and mouse is not over the video
  features: ['playpause','progress','current','duration','tracks','volume','sourcechooser','fullscreen'],
  alwaysShowControls: false
});
</script>
<script>
// JavaScript object for later use
var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#player');
// ... more code ...
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Do the videos play ok on the iPad if you put them in regular video tags instead of using mediaelement?

Comment: Does playing the videos from ipad count, or i have to upload them into a regular tag, wich by the way , what is the default tag for video without using javascript, HTML5?, you mean HMTL Video tag?

Comment: Yes, a video tag, like... <video src="movie.mp4" controls>